# Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. in IE8 and lower only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, crossdomain.xml

I have an issue with a flash application that is loaded in HTTP, then gets data from diffrent domains over HTTPS. The crossdomain.xml on each site is configured to support this and it works in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. However in IE8 and lower i get a 
"Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error" error. 
When using Charles to debug it i can see that the request is made and that its served by the server, which means that the error have to be caused when it tries to read the data it gets back. I have close to zero experience in programming in flash/as3 and have been looking at tons of similar questions on this site without finding a solution.
Seems this often relates to crossdomain or an incorrect url, but since it works in other browsers and all gets served according to charles this cannot be caused by that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An Unhandled ioError is just what it says. You are not handling the error. If you code in that handler your issue will go away. The reason it happens in IE8 is probably due to a different version of plugin/activeX installed. And one last note I vaguely remember reading somewhere that older versions of FPdo not support http->https requests which is probably the real reason why the error is triggered on that browser. Before you update the plug-in I would suggest coding in the error handler so people with that browser plugin combo will know whats going on.

Comment: OK ill implement an error handling and see if i can get some more info. I doubt its the FP not supporting HTTP->HTTPS since if that was the case the request should not been made, at least that's the general result when that's the issue. Thanks for the fast answer!